# Unsupported Media Type error in POST method

Tags: java, json, spring

I have problem with post method in controller

App got 2 model classes:

```
public class MovieGenre {

   @Id
   @Column(name = "genre_id")
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private Long genreId;

   @Column(name = "genre_name")
   private String genreName;

   @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "genres")
   @JsonBackReference
   private Set<Movie> movies = new HashSet<>();

// getters and setters
```

and

```
public class Movie {

   @Id
   @Column(name = "movie_id")
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private Long id;

   @Column(name = "movie_title")
   private String title;

   @Column(name = "production_year")
   private String year;

   @Column(name = "producer_name")
   private String producer;

   @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
   @JoinTable(
           name = "movie_movie_genre",
           joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "movie_id"),
           inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "movie_genre_id"))
   @JsonManagedReference
   private Set<MovieGenre> genres = new HashSet<>();

// getters and setters
```

MovieRepository:

```
public interface MovieRepository extends JpaRepository<Movie, Long> {
}
```

Movie services implements service like that

```
@Override
public Movie save(Movie object) {
   return movieRepository.save(object);
}
```

now Controller class

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "api/v1/movie", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public class MovieController {

   private final MovieService movieService;

   public MovieController(MovieService movieService) {
       this.movieService = movieService;
   }

   @GetMapping
   public ResponseEntity<Resources<Resource<Movie>>> getAll() {
       Resources<Resource<Movie>> resources = new Resources<>(
               movieService.findAll()
                       .map(this::createResource)
                       .collect(Collectors.toList())
       );
       resources.add(linkTo(methodOn(MovieController.class).getAll()).withSelfRel());
       return ResponseEntity.ok().body(resources);
   }



   @PostMapping(value = "/add", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
   public ResponseEntity<?> addNewMovie(@RequestBody Movie newMovie) {
       Movie addedMovie = movieService.save(newMovie);
       return ResponseEntity
               .created(URI.create(createResource(addedMovie).getLink("self").getHref()))
               .build();
   }

// some other code
```

Get method works without problems however when I do use Postman or curl to send JSON

```
{
    "title": "Toy story 3",
    "year": "2014",
    "producer": "Pixar",
    "genres": [
        {
            "genreId": 1,
            "genreName": "action"
        },
        {
            "genreId": 2,
            "genreName": "animation"
        },
        {
            "genreId": 3,
            "genreName": "comedy"
        }
    ]}
```

Im geting  in InteliJ console:

```
2019-10-28 16:51:43.206  WARN 29729 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] .c.j.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter : Failed to evaluate Jackson deserialization for type [[simple type, class com.progresspoint.movieapi.model.Movie]]: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot handle managed/back reference 'defaultReference': back reference type (java.util.Set) not compatible with managed type (com.progresspoint.movieapi.model.Movie)
2019-10-28 16:51:43.212  WARN 29729 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] .c.j.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter : Failed to evaluate Jackson deserialization for type [[simple type, class com.progresspoint.movieapi.model.Movie]]: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot handle managed/back reference 'defaultReference': back reference type (java.util.Set) not compatible with managed type (com.progresspoint.movieapi.model.Movie)
2019-10-28 16:51:43.217  WARN 29729 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' not supported]
```

In postman

```
{
   "timestamp": "2019-10-28T15:51:43.225+0000",
   "status": 415,
   "error": "Unsupported Media Type",
   "message": "Content type 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' not supported",
   "path": "/api/v1/movie/add"
}
```

I have seen many questions on stackoverflow about produces/consumes - this doesn't help here 
What Im doing wrong ?

Comment: @Deadpool I have bidirectional relationship between movie and movieGenre and I want to create joining table - thats why I used those annotations. How else I can do that?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to specify consumes key when you are using `@RequestBody`with one of the method arguments in controller.  @RequestBody suggests that it's `application/json`. you can try removing it.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't knew that. I removed it. It didnt help thou :)

Comment: Can you share the way you are calling the service url . With all the headers, parameters etc being provided?

Answer (score 1):

Remove `consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE` for `@PostMapping` you don't need to mention that.